# d3.event getting null with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, typescript

Apologies, if i am missing something or if this question being already answered. Please point me to the question where if it is being already answered.

Configuration as follows:

```
TypeScript v1.6.0-dev.20150907 
tslint v2.5.0-dev.5
d3 d3@^3.5.6
```

tsconfig.json:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noLib": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "../dist/"
  }
```

Now here is my minimum repo which i just wrote to describe my problem.

```
/// <reference path="tsd.d.ts" />
import * as React from "react";

interface INode extends d3.layout.tree.Node {
    id?: number;
    name?: string;
    x0?: number;
    y0?: number;
    weight?: number;
    _children?: INode[];
}

export class HelloMsg extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    private svg: d3.Selection<INode>;
    private zoomListener: d3.behavior.Zoom<INode>;
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    componentDidMount(): void {
        this.drawGraph();
    }
    zoomHandler(): void {
        // or d3.select(React.findDOMNode(this)).attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.behavior.zoom().translate() + ")scale(" + d3.behavior.zoom().scale() + ")");
        this.svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    }

    drawGraph() {
        this.zoomListener = d3.behavior.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([0.1, 3])
            // or .on("zoom", this.zoomHandler);
            .on("zoom", this.zoomHandler.bind(this));
        this.svg = d3.select(React.findDOMNode(this))
            .call(this.zoomListener.bind(this));
    }
    render(): JSX.Element {
        return <svg width={400} height={500}> </svg>;
    }
}
```

Now the compiler gives me an error Saying:

```
Property 'translate' does not exist on type 'Event'. 
Property 'scale' does not exist on type 'Event'.
```

and on the run time it gives d3.event as `null`

For the reference.
http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033
https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/d3/d3.d.ts

Please Suggest something, i am very new to both D3 and TypeScript, 
Apologies again if i am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem,  you need to do a casting on the event, then use it to get translate & scale.

`var evt:ZoomEvent = <d3.ZoomEvent> d3.event;
 this.svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + evt.translate + ")scale(" +     evt.scale + ")");`

For D3  It's impossible to really know what event is being handled since d3 uses a single global value, so they(the .d.ts file authors ) left it to user to handle the event casting.

Comment: I want to know how to translate this into a drag/drop question?